# Trying to annotate a PDF with XREF streams

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdf-parsing

I have this sample PDF file:

[Original file](http://db.tt/n5biHUBv)

which I tried to attach a text annotation to, which resulted in this:

[Annotated file](http://db.tt/upjNbWWR)

However, preview on MAC OSX still shows the document without the new annotation, where Adobe Reader can not even open the annotated document, stating:

> There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired.

I was pretty lucky till now annotating other files having the "classic XREF tables" not the encoded ones.
However, writing my own encoded XREF streams does not seem to work.
I am pretty sure my streams are ok, but still it might be something else I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which software you used to add annotations, but you should throw it away and never use it again. Why? Because it doesn't add a startxref entry in the trailer and therefore violates ISO-32000-1. Even files with compressed cross-reference tables need such an entry.

Read section 7.5.8 of ISO-32000-1 entitled "Cross-Reference Streams":

> **The value following the startxref keyword shall be the offset of the cross-reference stream** rather than
>   the xref keyword. For files that use cross-reference streams entirely
>   (that is, files that are not hybrid-reference files), the keywords xref and trailer shall no longer be
>   used. Therefore, **with the exception of the startxref address, %%EOF segment and comments**, a file may be entirely a sequence of
>   objects.

Comment: That's it! Sometimes you just can't see the wood for the trees!